# Error staking pyth.network

Tags: error, stake

I have this error
Can you help me please

failed to get transaction:
Transaction version (0) is not
supported by the requesting
client. Please try the request
again with the following
configuration parameter:
"maxSupportedTransactionVersion
O

Comment: If you're trying to invoke this via code, please post your code. If not, please contact Pyth directly as this forum is only meant for solana developers.